# How to clean xcode user specific settings (organizer, provisioning profiles)?

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, organizer

My xcode is crashing when i press the Refresh button in organizer. Seems there is some problem with certificate and provisioning profile.
If i log in as  another user in the same mac, everything is working fine.

So, can I clean the user specific settings without affecting the xcode installation? Like cleaning the organizer settings, provisioning profiles, etc.?

Comment: U can go and clean all the certificates.in the keychain

Comment: I did that, but seems I missed something again. If I download the certificates, I got team name unknown for all. And if I click refresh, xcode crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's Apple's official workaround:

Run /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app and execute the following statement:

> mkdir ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/OldPortalDBs; mv ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/connect1.apple.com* ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/OldPortalDBs

See: [Xcode 4.6.1 crashing while interacting with the developer portal](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/182876?tstart=0)

Comment: Thanks. Now I got it. But I already adopt the best solution :) To delete my user account, create it again and do everything from the scratch! That's a pain, but solved my problem.